# Dynamic Size to textfield and label iOS Swift Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift

**Dynamic Size to textfield and label in iOS Swift Storyboard,** *I need to change the size of UI Label and UI Textfield in storyboard dynamically in runtime and to match the size of the view*  "**Using Swift and storyboard design**"

I have gone through many coding samples online but i couldn't overcome this issue.
[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIWSD.png)

I need to reduce the space between the labels

Comment: Do you need multiple lined textfield based on text length?

Comment: Please share code and UI screenshots of your best attempt and explain where you're stuck.

Comment: Is it a homework ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please spend a few minutes taking the [tour] and reviewing [ask].

Comment: I need multiple lined textfield's  and labels which should vary the length based on the length of text inside it. No its not a home work

Comment: @CakstonMWS - *"I need to reduce the space between the labels"* -- **which** labels? How are they setup to begin with? When are you trying to change their sizes? ***PLEASE*** take a few minutes to review [ask].

Comment: i have added a image in the question there are 8 labels 4 (minimum maximum etc) i need to make the value closer to the labels dynamically when executing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i have designed using XCode storyboard